# Why is MIPS printing memory locations on the second time around

Tags: mips

[Solved]
We were tasked with writing a bubble sort in `MIPS` and printing both the unsorted and sorted arrays

I've written the following code to accomplish this.

But when I go to run it, the original array prints as I would expect

**Original Array**

```
[34, 23, -1, -2, 0]
```

But then it prints this for the sorted array.

**Sorted Array**

```
[173496791, 1818324585, 1920090400, 686433, 1919898378]
```

(the Unicode squares do print)

```
array: .word 34, 23, -1, -2, 0, 89
length: .word 6
original: .asciiz "Original Array\n"
sorted: .asciiz "\nSorted Array\n"
.text
# main()
main:
la $a2, length
lw $a2, 0($a2) # a2 <= n_element
add $t9, $0, $0 # t9 : counter
la $a1, array # a1 = &array[0]
addi $t0, $0, 0 # for t0=0 to
addi $a2, $a2, -1 # because we do [i+1]
#says prints original array
la $a0, original
li $v0, 4
syscall 
#prints array
jal print
#printing the string saying sorted
la $a0, sorted
li $v0, 4
syscall
#after printing original we reset the values?
la $a2, length
lw $a2, 0($a2) # a2 <= n_element
add $t9, $0, $0 # t9 : counter
add $t8, $0, $0 # t10 : counter 2
la $a1, array # a1 = &array[0]
addi $t0, $0, 0 # for t0=0 to
addi $a2, $a2, -1 # because we do [i+1]
#see if that worked it did
li $s0, 1 #boolean swapped = false 0=false 1=true
outerLoop:
    beqz $s0, exit #if flag is false exit
    li $s0, 0 
    addi $a1, $a1, 4 # next array offset
    addi $t9, $t9, 1 # counter++
    move $t8 $0
    sub $s2, $a2, $t9
    innerLoop:
        bge $t8, $s2, exitInner
        lw $t7, 0($a1) # t7 = array[i]
        lw $t8, 4($a1) # t8 = array[i+1]
        ble $t7, $t8, skip #if array[i]<= arr[i+1] skip the swapping
        sw $t8, 0($a1) #a[i+1] = a[1]
        sw $t7, 4($a1) #a[i] = a[i+1]
        li $s0, 1#flag update
        skip:
        addi $t8, $t8, 1 #count  
        addi $a1, $a1, 4
        j innerLoop
    exitInner:
        j outerLoop
exit:

la $a2, length
lw $a2, 0($a2) # a2 <= n_element
add $t9, $0, $0 # t9 : counter
addi $a2, $a2, -1 # because we do [i+1]
jal print
j quit#end Program
#print array 

print:
lw $t7,0($a1) # t7 = array[i]
lw $t8,4($a1) # t8 = array[i+1]

add $a0, $t7, 0
addi $v0, $0, 1 #print int using system call the value stored in a0
syscall
addi $a0, $0, 0x20 # ascii 0x20 = ' '
addi $v0, $0, 11
syscall

addi $a1, $a1, 4 # next array offset
addi $t9, $t9, 1 # counter++
beq $t9, $a2, return #return to the where we were we were at beforehand 
j print
return:
jr $ra
quit:
addi $v0, $0, 10
syscall
```

I think these are memory locations? I'm not sure why it's printing that as it is because I reset my counter values before trying to print. So the question is. Why am I printing memory locations? if that is what is happening

I was sorting in place so I had to reset the array before the print function.

Comment: I see at least a couple of weird things with that code: 1) You don't reset `$a1` before the second print. 2) You're trying to use `$t8` for multiple things in `innerLoop`.

Comment: You should use the debugging features in the simulator to inspect the runtime behavior of your code.

Comment: Michael I think I am reordering the values in a1 so if I reset it it would print the original array again

Comment: You're sorting in-place. The original array doesn't exist anymore after that.

Comment: Thank you I had been at that for hours now I am seeing that the logic isn't working perfectly but that can be worked around.